# Atom.io - When clicking a file in the tree, why doesn't it switch to it anymore?

Tags: atom-editor

I ended up updating Windows and had to re-download **Atom**, however, I had all my settings brought over with sync-settings. All has been good except something is up with the handling of my files when I click on them in the tree view.

What used to happen was if I clicked on a file, it would open directly to it in my main window pane. Now, however, when I click on a file, it opens it up in a new tab but doesn't switch to it. I have to manually do that.

I've searched everywhere but can't seem to find a solution. Why is it handling my files this way and how can I get it to go back to the way it was?

**EDIT: MY SOLUTION**

Ends up my issue was the Atom Debug UI package that was causing this behaviour. Once I disabled it, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

A single click on a file in the tree-view will open a "pending tab", as indicated by the use of italics on the tab. Pending tabs are meant as previews and will be closed unless you make edits or save the file. If you do want to edit a file, you need to *double-click* it. I don't recall older versions of Atom behaving differently, but I might be wrong.

Since Atom boasts itself as being "the hackable text editor", you can modify its default behaviour through packages or the [Init Script](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/the-init-file/) (by default that's `~/.atom/init.coffee`).

The following CoffeeScript snippet will create an event-listener for that behaviour:

```coffee
treeView = document.querySelector('.tree-view')

treeView.addEventListener 'click', ->
  editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
  view = atom.views.getView(editor)

  return view.focus()
```

Should you prefer using plain JavaScript, rename or delete your `~/.atom/init.coffee` and create an `init.js` in the same location. The JavaScript equivalent of the above looks like this:

```js
const treeView = document.querySelector('.tree-view');

treeView.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor();
  const view = atom.views.getView(editor);

  view.focus();
});
```

Comment: Oh no, I totally understand that. However, that's not my issue. My issue is that it opens the "Pending tab" however it doesn't switch to it like it used to. Say i have a file named index1.html open and i click to open index2.html in a pending tab. What used to happen would be my main pane would switch to index2.html in a pending tab. However, what's happening is that index1.html remains open and index2.html opens in a tab in the background.

Comment: Have you tried opening Atom in safe mode (`atom --safe`), to rule out a third-party package causing this behaviour?

Comment: Ah, that might be the issue. When I do that, the expected outcome works. I guess I'll have to disable each package until i figure out which one is doing it.

Comment: very curious if you come up with the offending package. I just started seeing the exact same behavior two days ago.

Comment: A quick tip if anyone is suffering from the same affliction.

Open your ~/.atom/packages folder and sort by modified date. I had 3 packages that were recently updated. Disabled the first one, restarted atom, BAM! working as expected again.

The offending package in my case was file-icons version 2.1.39

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: One more useful piece of info:
to roll this plugin back to the previous version run
`apm install file-icons@2.1.38`

Comment: @trejas This solved the annoying issue! Thank you!